# Continously Iterating each() loop in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, slider, each

Is it possible to continuously run an each() loop in jQuery?

I have a slideshow of images that fade in and out of eachother however when it gets to the last image it stops. My code is below:

**jQuery**

```
$('.slider-block').each(function(i) {

$(this).delay(4000*i).fadeTo(1000,1);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-block">

<img src="image1.png" />

</div>

<div class="slider-block">

<img src="image2.png" />

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-block { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
```

My aim is to have it loop through all the images and then go back to the first one and start all over again.

All the HTML and CSS works fine, its really only the jQuery part I need help with here.

** ***UPDATE*** **

Based on suggestions I have tried the following, however none of these loop through to the beginning again:

```
setTimeout(function(){  

$('.slider-block').each(function(i) { 

$(this).delay(4000*i).fadeTo(1000,1); }); 

} ,4000);
```

**and**

```
setInterval(function(){  

$('.slider-block').each(function(i) { 

$(this).delay(4000*i).fadeTo(1000,1); }); 

} ,4000);
```

**and this one crashes my browser**

```
while(true)
{
   $('.slider-block').each(function(i) {

       $(this).delay(4000*i).fadeTo(1000,1);

   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
function cycleImages(){
    var $active = $('#slider-container .active');
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('.slider-block:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
}        
$(function(){
    // run every 4s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 4000);            
});
```

**EDITED Answer (v2):**

Top Image has a z-index of '3'. The next image is placed underneath is using a z-index of '2'. Therefore by fading out the top image, you have the impression that it is fading in seamlessly.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UhJm6/1/

**NOTE:** This solution will not work with images of type '.png' due to transparency issues. Use JPEG images by preference.

Source: http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/

Comment: Added working solution and explained the problem. Revert back if it works for you :)

Comment: Ahh yes Mysteryos that makes a lot of sense! I have done this and it now loops, just one issue with this is that the image completely fades out leaving just the background for a while before the next image comes in, they really need to seamlessly fade in and out of eachother... You can see my dev site [here](http://lions.networkintellect4.info/)

Comment: Yeah, i saw that. Let it fix it ;)

Comment: New solution for you. Tried and working with images from your website :)

Don't forget to use the CSS as per JS fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the update... Im looking at your jsfiddle however the images dont appear to be fading in and out?

Comment: Also the other problem is that im fading not only images but images with text over the top etc as you can see on the dev site

Comment: Fixed jsfiddle to make it work and respected the div structure in place on your website. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this! Youve been an absolute star, and gone out of your way to help, if I could award 10 upvotes I would...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTimeout()` function of Javascript to create an infinite loop.

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

If you don't want any pause, just set the timeout time accordingly.

Or either you can use this

```
While(true)
{
   $('.slider-block').each(function(i) {
       $(this).delay(4000*i).fadeTo(1000,1);
   });
}
```

Comment: Hi The-Val, thanks for the response, however I just copied your code above directly and it made my browser crash...?

Comment: Also I just tried this `setTimeout(function(){  $('.slider-block').each(function(i) { $(this).delay(4000*i).fadeTo(1000,1); }); },4000);` however that didn't make it loop either...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the complete parameter of `fadeTo` to set next fade like this :

```
function fadeImg(i) {
    $('.slider-block').eq(i).delay(4000 * i).fadeTo(1000, 1, function () {
        fadeImg(i);
    });
}
$('.slider-block').each(function (i) {
    fadeImg(i);
});
```

But you'll have to hide them back once you've reach the end of the loop, otherwise they will be hidden by the last one.
Something like that :

```
function fadeIn(i) {
    $('.slider-block').eq(i).delay(4000 * i).fadeTo(1000, 1, function () {
        fadeIn(i);
        fadeOut(i);
    });
}
function fadeOut(i) {
    $('.slider-block').eq(i).delay(4000 * (i+1)).fadeTo(1000, 0);
}
$('.slider-block').each(function (i) {
    fadeIn(i);
});
```

Sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D3aS5/2/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it has finally started looping back to the start again however the timings are very strange, ocassionaly 1 second between them, ocassionaly it jumps through two in a split second...

Answer (score 0):

let's imagine that you want to do an "each" Continuously on below array:

```
var your_array = [1, 2, 3];
```

you can write a function for walking on this array and then when you reached the last one you can run the function again:

```
var your_array = [1, 2, 3];
next = function () {
    var length = your_array.length,
        new_num;
    $.each(your_array, function(key, value) {
        new_num = value;
        if (length == key+1) {//we understand that we reached to the end of array
            alert(new_num);
            next();
        } else {
            alert(new_num);
        }

    });
}
next(); //output: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...
```